# Determining missing data

Tags: java

I have text file.  It contains delimited data in each line like,

```
120 US 1 ALASKA 4.
```

in some lines some data are missing. like,

```
US 1 ALASKA 4
```

Since it is delimited by space, i am using split to get the tokens.  I am not able to determine which data is missing.

In the below code, sample input1 will validate `120` for `^[1-9]+$`. If the `120` is missing in the line, as in sample `input2`, the `token[0]` will have `US`, It will validate for `^[1-9]+$` and give `"Error in a"`.  Instead of this, i want to know which value is missing.  So, that i can display the error `"Error a i missing"` and the `token[1]` should contain `US`, so that i can validate correctly.

Can someone give some idea for doing the above?

```
        String line = "120 US 1 ALASKA 4"; //Sample input1
       //String line = "US 1 ALASKA 4"; //Sample input2
        String delimiter = "[ ]+";
        String tokens[] = line.split(delimiter);

        String a = tokens[0];
        String b = tokens[1];
        String c = tokens[2];
        String d = tokens[3];
        String e = tokens[4];

        //Sample validation
        if(a.matches("^[1-9]+$")){
           System.out.println("Matches");
        }else{
           System.out.println("Error in a");
        }
```

Comment: is your pattern always going to be `<number> <2char> <number> <a_word> <number>`?

Comment: @shiva0101 m : see my updated answer... code is working for your two inputs that you requested..

Answer (score 0):

you can something like below (considering you have four elements) and your pattern is number string number string number

```
if (firstdata is not a number & firstdata is String) {
    //display alert as first data is missing
    // move the token data
    e=d;
    d=c;
    c=b;
    b=a;
}
```

do same for second place data and so on...

to determine what is missing, you will have to move the data...

### **Update 1**

Below is what I meant.... This is tried and tested code and works perfectly for two inputs that you provided..

```
public class checkForPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String line = "120 US 1 ALASKA 4"; // Sample input1
        // String line = "US 1 ALASKA 4"; //Sample input2
        String delimiter = "[ ]+";
        String tokens[] = line.split(delimiter);

        String a = "", b = "", c = "", d = "", e = "";
        try {
            a = tokens[0];
            b = tokens[1];
            c = tokens[2];
            d = tokens[3];
            e = tokens[4];
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }

        System.out.println("String is : " + line);
        // Sample validation
        if (a.matches("((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+")) {
            System.out.println("Position First Matches.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in first position.");
            e = d;
            d = c;
            c = b;
            b = a;
        }

        if (!(b.matches("((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+"))) {
            System.out.println("Position Two Matches.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in second position.");
            e = d;
            d = c;
            c = b;
        }

        if (c.matches("((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+")) {
            System.out.println("Position Three Matches.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in third position.");
            e = d;
            d = c;
        }

        if (!(d.matches("((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+"))) {
            System.out.println("Position Four Matches.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in fourth position.");
            e = d;
        }

        if (e.matches("((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+")) {
            System.out.println("Position Five Matches.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in fifth position.");
            e = d;
            d = c;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following approach:

- break a line into tokens.
- analyze each token to determine the possible positions it might belong (Strings can go only on position 2 or 4, Ints on 1,3 or 5. Long Strings must be position 5 ...
- since the positions for tokens must be increasing you can determine the possible missing tokens.

Answer (score 0):

It's Saturday! Let's write a method for you, this assumes the pattern is `<number> <2char> <number> <a_word> <number>`, well you can change the pattern. It's simple.

```
public static boolean validate(String line){
     String delimiter = "[\\s]+";
     String[] tokens = line.split(delimiter);
     int i=0;
     for(String s: tokens){
         switch (i) {
            case 0:
                if(!s.matches("\\d+")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("First element missing");
                break;

            case 1:
                if(!s.matches("\\w{2}")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("2nd element missing");
                break;

            case 2:
                if(!s.matches("\\d+")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("3rd element missing");
                break;

            case 3:
                if(!s.matches("\\w+")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("4th element missing");
                break;

            case 4:
                if(!s.matches("\\d+")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("5th element missing");
                break;

        }
         i++;
     }

     if(i<4)throw new IllegalArgumentException((i+1)+" element missing");
     return true;
}
```

If you're not of my taste, you would prefer returning `false` where I threw exception.

Answer (score 0):

For a syntax like this, I think you'll do better using `Scanner`.  For instance (and you'll need to check method names, parameter types, etcetera)

```
    String line = "120 US 1 ALASKA 4";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
    scanner.useDelimiter(" +"); // set the field delimiter regex.
    int value1, value2, value3;

PARSE: 
    try {
        value1 = scanner.nextInt();
        if (!scanner.next().equals("USA")) {
            ...
            break PARSE; // or throw ...
        }
        value2 = scanner.nextInt();
        if (!scanner.next().equals("ALASKA")) {
            ...
            break PARSE; // or throw ...
        }
        value3 = scanner.nextInt();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        ...
    }
```

If one of the fields is missing, then you'll either get a non-integer at a point where an integer is expected (and hence a `NoSuchElementException`) or one of the calls to `next()` will return the wrong marker string and the `equals` test will fail.